# Как узнать загруженность интернет канала, Java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, debian, ethernet

Добрый день! Имеется немного специфическая проблема, подскажите как решить.

---

**Дано**: ftp-сервер на Debain based ОС с которого постоянно идет загрузка файлов определенным количеством пользователей. Скорость каждого подключения — разная. Максимальная скорость отдачи сервера составляет 100 Мбит\сек.

**Требуется**: узнать силу загруженности интернет канала (через скорость отдачи в данный момент), получая статистику каждые n секунд, допустим, используя паттерн "Наблюдатель". Результат должен быть в виде числового значения, подразумевающего кбит\сек.

Например: *текущая скорость отдачи 100 кбит\сек.*

**Вопрос**: как можно получить эту статистику? Есть ли какие-то методы в стандартной Java-библиотеке или сторонних библиотеках, позволяющие получить текущую скорость отдачи в данный момент (периодический "опрос" можно сделать вручную)? Или как это реализовать другим способом?

---

**Варианты решения**: единственный вариант решения, который вышло найти — через команду `exec` использовать Linux-программу дающую статистику и попросту парсить ответ. Но, как оказалось, все такие программы очень и очень плохо поддаются парсингу из-за динамической работы в своем консольном "окне" и это займет много времени на написание парсера. Поэтому я ищу более правильный вариант.

Comment: Если нужна статистика не всего по сетевой карте а более выборочная, например только по портам ftp, то делайте записи в iptables и считывайте счетчики с них

Comment: @Mike, так я найду среднее значение за все время, а мне нужно реальное значение в **данный момент времени**. Такой вариант, к сожалению, не подойдет.

Comment: @Mike, хм... Действительно. Результат, правда, будет немного некорректным, а приблизительным, но подойдет. Вечером попробую.Добавьте в ответ, если не сложно, я приму.

Comment: вопрос точности это только с какой частотой читать значения и за какой интервал времени усреднять. так же, конечно не надо полагаться на время на которое вас заморозит sleep (или чем вы будете выжидать время) и получать текущее время, можно в миллисекундах. Все что делают всякие там MRTG когда строят свои графики загрузки - это коллекционируют значения раз в минуту или 5 минут даже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Периодически (раз в несколько секунд) считывайте статистику, количество прошедших байт по сетевому интерфейсу. Статистика находится в файлах `/sys/class/net/устройство-смотрящее-в-интернет/statistics/??_bytes` (?? = rx или tx). Вычисляете на сколько изменились счетчики и делите на прошедшее время - получаете среднюю скорость на данном интервале времени. Есть смысл всегда получать текущее время, а не ориентироваться на время, которое мы ожидали следующей порции данных, потому что задержка даваемая функциями на подобии `sleep()` лишь приблизительная.

Пример: прочитали счетчик RX (принято байт), получили 200000000. Через 5 секунд прочитали еще раз, теперь он показал 21228800. Делим 1228800/5 получаем 240КБайт в секунду (1.9 МБит).